# SimpleAttribute instead of Attribute in Rapidminer script?

Tags: groovy, attributes, rapidminer

I am trying to extract an Attribute from an ExampleSet in a RapidMiner 'Execute script' like this:

```
ExampleSet exSet = input[0]; 
Attributes attrs = exSet.getAttributes(); 
Attribute attr = attrs.getAttribute("h_area");
```

but then I get an error and it says that attrs is not a Attributes but a SimpleAttributes object.

This works:

```
Attribute[] attrs2 = exSet.createRegularAttributeArray(); 
Attribute attr2 = attrs2.getAt(1);
```

What is the correct way to get an Attribute from an ExampleSet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [these docs](http://www-ai.cs.uni-dortmund.de/LEHRE/VORLESUNGEN/MLRN/WS0809/rm-api/index.html?com/rapidminer/example/set/package-summary.html), it looks like the `getAttributes()` call will return an object implementing the `Attributes` abstract class, which `SimpleAttributes` is, so it looks pretty fair at this stage. However, the `getAttribute()` method doesn't look like it's defined in either object. I can't test this here and now, but have you tried the following:

```
ExampleSet exSet = input[0]; 
Attributes attrs = exSet.getAttributes(); 
Attribute attr = attrs.get("h_area");
```

Comment: Yes, the .get("AttributeName") should do the trick. Also feel free to ask further, or re-post, questions in the RapidMiner community forum (http://community.rapidminer.com/).

Comment: Yes it works! I just got confused with the many classes with similar names.